# How to handle View model/data and server returned model/data in angular 2 or above apps?

Tags: angular, mvvm

The server is returning following type of data:

```
class TripModel{
    status: string; // status can be started, ended
    ....
}
```

**View Requirement:** status can be *In Progress and Completed*. started must be mapped to '*In Progress*' and ended would be mapped to '*Completed*'

Currently, I'm using controller's method for doing such mapping and calling this method from the template.

My mapping becomes complicated as we have other conditions as well :

```
 /**
   * Get mapped trip status for the view
   * @param status - trip status
   * @param auctionId - trip auction id
   * @return mapped trip status
   */
  public getMappedTripStatus(status: string, auctionId: string) {
    let tripStatus = '';
    if (status == Constants.tripStatus.started) {
      tripStatus = 'IN PROGRESS';
    } else if (status == Constants.tripStatus.ended) {
      tripStatus = 'COMPLETED';
    } else if (status == Constants.tripStatus.confirmed && auctionId) {
      tripStatus = 'SCHEDULED';
    }
    return tripStatus;
  }
```

What is the best approach?

Comment: Why to go to server just for a data model?

Comment: modified the question. Let me know if still not clear.